# Cron job not running python

Tags: cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to get cron to run a python file but it doesn't seem to run. The command in cron is:

```
24 21 * * * python /mnt/c/Users/saifl/git/StaffTrainingLog/automate.py
```

And the following appeared in the log:

```
Feb 16 21:24:01 MSI CRON[3839]: (slatifi) CMD (python /mnt/c/Users/saifl/git/StaffTrainingLog/automate.py)
```

However, it doesn't actually run the code. When I run the command in backets above it works with no issues. Please advise.

**Update (after Romeo's responce):**

I have now move the command to a script (automate_script):

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
cd /mnt/c/Users/saifl/git/StaffTrainingLog
/usr/bin/python3 automate.py
```

And I now have the following in Crontab:

```
50 14 * * * /mnt/c/Users/saifl/git/StaffTrainingLog/automate_script
```

And when running `/mnt/c/Users/saifl/git/StaffTrainingLog/automate_script` in the command line it works, however, it does run with cron as it appears in the log but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... your cron is set properly and it is working. The problem is probably with your script.
Maybe you forgot to add the exec permission to it?
Try running `chmod +x path/to/your/script` and then run your cron again.

Comment: This isn't the issue as I can run python /mnt/c/Users/saifl/git/StaffTrainingLog/automate.py in the console and it'll work

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to do when you execute such script. And its better to create dedicated script for this purpose.

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
cd /mnt/c/Users/saifl/git/StaffTrainingLog
/path/to/python  automate.py
```

1. Source the `.bashrc` to get your environment settings
2. cd to directory where the script is located
3. run it with absolute path to `python`

and run the above script in cron

```
24 21 * * * /path/to/the/script
```

Do not forget to make the script executable

Comment: Thanks - what extension should be script be?

Comment: I tried to do the above without a file extension and the following appeared in the log but still nothing happened:

Comment: Feb 17 14:17:01 MSI CRON[4235]: (slatifi) CMD (/mnt/c/Users/saifl/git/StaffTrainingLog/automate_script)
Feb 17 14:17:01 MSI CRON[4234]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)